# How to get the process id (pid) of a running process inside a tmux pane?

Tags: linux, tmux

I am running a python program inside a tmux pane. Occasionally, the python process becomes a zombie and I need to kill it, by using its pid. However, this command

```
tmux list-panes -F '#{pane_active} #{pane_pid}'
```

only provides the pid of the bash inside the pane, which cannot be killed. So how can I get the pid of the python process?

Comment: `pstree` might be useful here?

Comment: Why do you need the pid? You can kill a python program via `pkill -9 <name>` if it has a unique name.

Comment: @tink I usually run many python programs and they are both named "python"

Comment: i don't think tmux would bother to track  these dead processes.

Comment: Why? https://imgur.com/a/lqzH5aw